`dotnet test` - exception stacktrace without /agent/_work/1/s
When I get an exception during dotnet test on Azure DevOps, the stacktrace is printed.
Current output:
 Failed MyTest [54 s]
  Error Message:
   System.Exception: Parse failed
  Stack Trace:
     at MyTests.End2End.LocatorExtensions.InputValueAsEnumAsync[T](ILocator locator, LocatorInputValueOptions options) in /agent/_work/1/s/Backend/MyTests/End2End/Extensions/LocatorExtensions.cs:line 60
   at MyTests.End2End.Pages.MyPage.Assert(IReadOnlyList`1 allJaarcijfers) in /agent/_work/1/s/Backend/MyTests/End2End/Pages/MyPage.cs:line 81

Unfortunately, the path contains the prefix /agent/_work/1/s and as result, clicking the line in the test panel (in Azure DevOps) won't navigate correctly.
It is possible to get the stack trace lines without the /agent/_work/1/s?
e.g.
/agent/_work/1/s/Backend/MyTests/End2End/Pages/MyPage.cs:line 81
should be
/Backend/MyTests/End2End/Pages/MyPage.cs:line 81
Could we configure this with dotnet test, MS build properties or somewhere in Azure DevOps?
I'm using C#, .NET 8, xUnit 2.8.1 and Azure DevOps Services

The path is not "wrong". The stack trace will always show the absolute path of the file, depending on where you run the tests: local machine (e.g. C:\src\Backend\...) or build agent (e.g. /agent/_work/1/s/Backend/...).

@RuiJarimba you're right, I corrected my wording

There is no direct method to eliminate the /agent/_work/1/s prefix from the stack trace. This prefix is a component of the file path where the Azure DevOps agent executes the tests and is incorporated into the stack trace by the .NET runtime.
I tested the issue in my pipeline, and I can reproduce your issue. When click the stack trace in the test tap, it will navigate to a File not found page.


Workaround
I found when I changed the vmImage from ubuntu-latest to windows-latest, it will navigate to the correct line of the file.

I also tested with the macOS agent and found the same issue.
Currently, it seems that only the paths of Windows agents can be navigated correctly. I have created a ticket to report the bug. You can follow it for the update.
